# Equality comparison of the input field value not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the `if` statement bellow only the `else` block executes even when the when the answer is 10!

## JavaScript

```js
$("#correctOne").hide();
$("#incorrectOne").hide();

function myFunction() {
  var inputOne = $("#inputOne").value;
  if (inputOne === 10) {
    $("#correctOne").show();

  } else {
    $("#incorrectOne").show();

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>What number am I thinking of?</h1>
<p>Divide me by four and my remainder is two. I am net if you see me through the looking glass.</p>
<form>
  <input id="inputOne" type="text" placeholder="Answer Here">

  <button onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>
</form>
<h2 id="correctOne">Yes!</h2>
<h3 id="incorrectOne">Nope!</h3>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.value` is JavaScript and only works for InputElements, you have `$("#inputOne')`, a jQuery object, and thus need `.val()`.

Next, if you enter 10 into the field, inputOne is `"10"`, not `10`, but `===` also compares type.

Use `==` instead.

Comment: Instead of `==` you should convert it to number and then equate.

Comment: @Rajesh Why? The only correct answer is `"10"`, and `"10" == 10` will evaluate to `true`. There's no compelling reason to turn it into a number and use `===`, is there?

Comment: You should avoid `==` as type conversion will give you issues later. Also if value expected is numeric, you should convert it to number and evaluate it with number. This enforces correct values. 1 sample is if you expect `0` as input. Now this will be `true` even for blank string for `==` but will be `false` for `===`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code with code snippet.

I have change `.val()` instead of `.value()`.
-- Another change is change `10` to `"10"`
-- Another change is changing `==` to `===`

```js
$("#correctOne").hide();
    $("#incorrectOne").hide();

    function myFunction() {
        var inputOne = $("#inputOne").val();
        if (inputOne == "10") {
            $("#correctOne").show();

        } else {
            $("#incorrectOne").show();

        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>What number am I thinking of?</h1>
<p>Divide me by four and my remainder is two. I am net if you see me through the looking glass.</p>
<form>
    <input id="inputOne" type="text" placeholder="Answer Here">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">submit</button>
</form>
<h2 id="correctOne">Yes!</h2>
<h3 id="incorrectOne">Nope!</h3>
```

Answer (score -2):

The syntax is `var inputOne ==$('#inputOne).val();`

`val()` is the method to retrieve the value in an element.
`html()` method can set the inner HTML content too.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to say. `#inputOne` is a input so it should be `.val()` and not `.html()`. Also you have `==` instead of `=` in assignment

Comment: == is for comparison.

Comment: Mate, I know that but `var variableName == something` is a syntax error. You should first try your code before putting